# How to mock and return a value for a method inside a testing class method in Mock?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, easymock

**Test class**

```
class testClass{
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
    public class testmethod1(){
        ClassNeedToMocked clasNeedToMocked=createNiceMock();
        ExpectNew(ClassNeedToMocked).andReturn(class1).anytimes();     // have to mock from two methods
        expect(classNeedToMocked.someMethod()).andReturn(returnvalue); // even return null while put .anyTimes()
        replayAll();                                                   // tried replay() and replayAll()
        Map<> reponseMap=classUnderTest.method1();
    }
}
```

**Class under test**

```
ClassUnderTest{
    public method1(){
        ClassNeedToMocked classNeedToMocked = new ClassNeedToMocked();
        Set<String> set = method2();
    }
    public method2(){
        ClassNeedToMocked classNeedToMocked = new ClassNeedToMocked();
        returnvalue = classNeedToMocked.smoeMethod();                  // return Null here
        return returnvalue;
    }
}
```

The above code returns null, but mocked `.expect().andReturn` is not working.

Comment: Please edit your code into the question directly.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question and typed the code from the screenshot. To make it a better question, you should describe what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: above code is syntactically not correct, no return types mentioned for the methods declared in ClassUnderTest.